# Calculate $f(3)$ such that $f(f(x))=x^2-5x+9$

Tags: functions

How can one calculate $f(3)$ when $f(f(x))=x^2-5x+9$

I tried this:
$f(f(3))=3$

I'm stuck here.

Comment: Setting $x^2-5x+9=t$ then we get $x_{1,2}=5/2\pm \sqrt {t-11/4}$ and you will get $f(t)=...$

Comment: Your initial statement should be phrased as "Calculate $f(3)$ where $f(f(x)) = x^2 - 5x + 9$." ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$f(f(f(x))) = f(x^2 - 5x +9) = f(x)^2 - 5 f(x) + 9$.

set $x = 3$, then $f(3) = f(3)^2 - 5 f(3) + 9$. then $f(3) = 3$

Comment: how did you get $f(x)^2 - 5 f(x) + 9$.?

Comment: using $f(f(y)) = y^2 - 5y +9$, replace $y$ as $f(x)$. @user233658

Answer (score 4):

Since $f(f(3))=3^2-5\cdot 3+9=3$, we have
$$f(3)=f(f(f(3)))=(f(3))^2-5f(3)+9,$$
i.e.
$$(f(3)-3)^2=0.$$
So, $f(3)=3$.

Answer (score 4):

If $f(3) = y$, then $f(y) = f(f(3)) = 3$, and $f(f(y)) = f(3) = y$.
But $0 = f(f(y)) - y = y^2 - 6 y + 9 = (y - 3)^2$, so $y = 3$.